# Slice of pointers to a struct golang issue

Tags: go, pointers, slice

I have a function in my repository layer which should return a slice of pointers, but the code does not work properly.

```
var books []model.Book

func GetBooksByGenre(genre string) []*model.Book {
    var response []*model.Book
    for _, ele := range books {
        if ele.Genre == genre {
            response = append(response, &ele)
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

I am trying to iterate over the list of books and finally return a slice of pointers based on the `genre` of the book matching the input genre.

I debugged and found that the issue is there due to `ele` getting updated and messing up the existing pointers in the var `response`

The problem is that if there are 3 books inserted in the order of `genre` as `comedy`, `thriller` and `drama` and if **GetBooksByGenre** is called with `genre` as `comedy` or `thriller`, then the output is coming as `drama` as that is the last entry when I iterate the list.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The program fills the slice with the address of variable `ele`.  One fix is to use the address of the slice element:

```
func GetBooksByGenre(genre string) []*model.Book {
    var response []*model.Book
    for i, ele := range books {
        if ele.Genre == genre {
            response = append(response, &books[i])
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

Another fix is to change `books` to be a `[]*model.Book` instead of a `[]model.Book`. Use this code with that change:

```
func GetBooksByGenre(genre string) []*model.Book {
    var response []*model.Book
    for _, ele := range books {
        if ele.Genre == genre {
            response = append(response, ele)
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

Yet another fix is to create a new variable for each iteration and use the address of that variable:

```
func GetBooksByGenre(genre string) []*model.Book {
    var response []*model.Book
    for _, ele := range books {
        if ele.Genre == genre {
            ele := ele // <-- new variable
            response = append(response, &ele)
        }
    }
    return response
}
```

You probably want one of the first two options presented here.